# Why, with ReactJS, am I failing to make checkboxes that react to being clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of (mostly) checkboxes, which I have tried to specify a handler which (now) is set to log the checkbox's ID, and then update state so that on next render the checkbox's state will be toggled.

What I am not quite understanding is why checking one of the checkboxes doesn't seem to "stick". More specifically, the user interface does not change on clicking a checkbox, and the event handler is not doing its console.log().

My render method is below; a TL;DR of render method contents immediately follows, followed by the event handler that doesn't seem to be registering.

```
  render: function()
    {
    var table_rows = [];
    var display_item_details = function(label, item)
      {
      var html_id = item.id + '.' + label;
      return (
        <td className={label} title={label}>
          <input id={html_id} onChange={this.handle_change}
          className={label} type="checkbox"
          checked={item[label]} />
        </td>
        );
      };
    var display_item = function(item)
      {
      var rendered_nodes = [];
      for(var index = 0; index < todo_item_names.length;
        index += 1)
        {
        rendered_nodes.push(
          display_item_details(todo_item_names[index], item)
          );
        }
      return (
          <tr>{rendered_nodes}
          <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
            converter.makeHtml(item.description)}} /></tr>
        );
      };
    table_rows.push(this.state.items.map(display_item));
    table_rows.reverse();
    return (
      <div id="Todo">
        <h1>To do</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <table>
            {table_rows}
            <tfoot>
              <textarea onChange={this.onChange}
               value={this.state.text}></textarea><br />
              <button>{'Add activity'}</button>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

TL;DR of render method:

```
        <td className={label} title={label}>
          <input id={html_id} onChange={this.handle_change}
          className={label} type="checkbox"
          checked={item[label]} />
        </td>
```

Event handler that doesn't seem to be getting called:

```
  handle_change: function(event)
    {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    var address = event.target.id.split('.', 2);
    (this.state.items[parseInt(address[0])][address[1]] =
      !this.state.items[parseInt(address[0])][address[1]]);
    save('Todo', this.state);
    },
```

The HTML ID's are something like `3.Important`.

Is there something else I need to wire up?

Thanks,

Comment: What's probably going on here is because the components are being formed in these subfunctions, the `this` variable gets lost, resulting in `this.handle_change` being equal to `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Your event handler is not being called and your checkbox is not accepting user input because you created a **Controlled Component**.

See here for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

If you want to create an Uncontrolled checkbox, you cannot specify the `checked` attribute, as that is what tells React to make it a Controlled Component.

If you would like to specify a default value for the checkbox, use 'defaultChecked' instead.  This will specify the default value **on the initial render only**.

If you would like an Uncontrolled Component that is also linked to some state, use the [LinkedStateMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

Here is a JSBin that demonstrates how to do each of these, and what the results look like: http://jsbin.com/vefowe/edit?js,output

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the `this` context is being lost. Functions do not automatically inherit the `this` context. One way to fix this is to mend `display_item_details` like so:

```
var display_item_details = function(label, item)
{
var html_id = item.id + '.' + label;
return (
  <td className={label} title={label}>
    <input id={html_id} onChange={this.handle_change}
    className={label} type="checkbox"
    checked={item[label]} />
  </td>
  );
}.bind(this);
```

For those using ES2015, an arrow function would achieve the same outcome.